# Are there functions for file paths, instead of just urls

Tags: plugins-url

Is there any equivalent to functions like `plugins_url()` and `content_url()` that give you either the relative paths or the file path.

For instance, instead of

> http://localhost:8888/wordpress-3.2/wp-content

I want:

> /Users/username/Sites/wordpress-3.2/wp-content

I know that I can build this path using the `ABSPATH` constant, but I'm specifically interested in learning if there are built in functions to handle this.

In the meantime, I'll probably just write a function to swap the url for the abspath.

EDIT: Here's the simple function that I wrote to handle this:

```
function get_file_path($url)
{
    return str_replace(site_url(), ABSPATH, $url);
}
```

Seems to do the trick, but I'd much rather use built in functions if available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There aren't any for plugins, but you can (and should) use WP_CONTENT_DIR, instead of ABSPATH.

For themes you have locate_template().

Comment: Thanks scribu! Funny thing is the project I was working with attempted to redefined `WP_CONTENT_DIR`.

Comment: As per my answer there **is** `WP_PLUGIN_DIR`, plugins are not strictly tied to content. Gave me a lot of grief recently. :)

Comment: @Rarst After Scribu's answer, I looked around where `WP_CONTENT_DIR` was defined and found `WP_PLUGIN_DIR`. Nice to know these exist. I've ridded the project of ABSPATH!

Answer (score 2):

There is [`plugin_dir_path()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugin_dir_path), but it's not exact analogue of `plugins_url()`.

Also `ABSPATH` is unreliable for how you use it, related paths can be easily redefined. See [`default-constants.php`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.2/wp-includes/default-constants.php) file.

Namely there are:

- `WP_CONTENT_DIR`
- `WP_PLUGIN_DIR`
- `WPMU_PLUGIN_DIR`